# How to construct an even, connected graph from a given graphNEL object?

Tags: r, graph

I have a `graphNEL` object representing a graph. I would like to apply some operation to it such that an even, connected graph results. To this end, I found `PairViz`'s `mk_even_graph()` but that throws a warning I don't understand. I am wondering if there is a different approach to constructing an even, connected graph, maybe just with the `graph` package?

```
require(graph)
require(PairViz)
require(Rgraphviz)

ft <- cbind(from=c("A","A","D"), to=c("B","C","E"))
W <- 1:nrow(ft)
graph <- ftM2graphNEL(ft, W=W, edgemode="undirected")
plot(graph) # not connected yet

cgraph <- mk_even_graph(graph)
plot(cgraph) # connected & even; but why the warning?
```

Comment: It is only a warning, so perhaps nothing to worry about (flw). Quick look is it seems to stem from using the weighted argument. Try `mk_even_graph(graph, weighted=FALSE)`. So you could step through the code to see exactly when the warning is issued. To see the code use `getMethod("mk_even_graph","graphNEL")`

Comment: okay, stepped through the functions. Goes from `pairoff`, to 
`find_tour_start`, to `min2` which throws the error. (to see code use `getAnywhere`).
Llooks like the warning comes, if there are <= 2 nodes with the minimum edge weight.
Due to how the function is written, it trie to take the minimum of a zero length vector, hence warning.
`min(integer(0))`